# Pulling the files using SFTP from a server

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop

I have to pull some files on a daily basis from a remote server, I have the servers username, ipaddress and password. I'm able to login using

```
sftp username@ipaddress
```

password prompt will appear after that, I have the password so I will enter.

But what I want to know here is how can I make this automate through the script as I want pull the files everyday.
Any commands that I can use to automate through script ?
That particular server is only accessible through sftp, no ssh is allowed. I tried scp command too but the server only accepts sftp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with Oracle or MySQL or hadoop? Please remove irrelevant tags

Comment: I'm new to the stack. Any way Hadoop and oracle people uses unix right ? so they might have idea.

Comment: searching here for `[linux] [bash] sftp script` shows 36 Q/As. You should read thru them as I'm certain there is a least one good scripted solution. Generally, requests as this are considered off-topic for StackOverflow. We're here to help you fix you broken code, not help you specify or code it. So please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pentaho data integration ,it has a step that can pull the files, and move them to whatever you need(including another file location, insert int on a database or in hadoop hdfs)

Answer (score 0):

I think crontab, shell script and [lftp](http://lftp.tech/) will be suitable for this purpose.